# How do i get remaining split string in one line of string or useing substr() function

Tags: php, string, split

I have string **ces123456789101112131415**
in the code below. I want to be able to start split from **123456789101112131415** and alter result in index size then try to get the remaining unsplit text in just one line string example expecting **1234** **5678** **9101** **112131415** In result

I have tried:

```
$code = "ces123456789101112131415";
      $start = preg_split("/ces/", $code);
      $result = str_split($start[1], 4);
      for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++);
       {
       echo $result[$b];
        }
       $total= 0;
       $cnt = strlen($result[$b]);
       $total += $cnt;
       $pay = substr($code,$total);
       echo "remain $pay";
```

but I get **1234** **5678** **9101** **123456789101112131415** as result 
Am expecting just **1234** **5678** **9101** **112131415** thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: can you please explain little more

Comment: Could you explain the criteria of your string extraction? Like maybe you want the last n number of integer or something

Comment: Is this an explanation of what you try to do? *Remove CES and 12 next characters*?

Comment: Your edit does not make it any clearer than before.

Comment: It will be much easier if you just answer our questions. Your edits don't do nothing for readability

Comment: Have edited to my want i dont really no how to state questions in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds ces in string and skips 12 characters, then captures the following digits.
Is that what you are trying to do?

```
$code = "ces123456789101112131415";
Preg_match("/ces.{12}(\d+)/", $code, $match);
$pay = $match[1];

Echo $pay;
```

https://3v4l.org/FQ5iX

Comment: to your method how do i use variable as example
$code = "ces12345678910111213141516";
$do == 12;
    Preg_match("/ces.{$do}(\d+)/", $code, $match);

    $pay = $match[1];



    Echo $pay;

Comment: @Kingsley `Preg_match("/ces.{" . $do. "}(\d+)/", $code, $match); `

Comment: @Kingsley got it to work? I see you have `==` at $do. You should only have `=`. See here https://3v4l.org/FD1ZV